# Execute a js function only after the ajax request fully compleated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I want to execute a js function only after the jquery ajax call fully completed.(After Success and Error Events completed). ie after ajax call puts incoming data to an element.

How to achive this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 16):

You should use [$.ajaxComplete();](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  alert("compete");
});
```

this would be triggered after every Ajax call you make on the page

otherwise you use [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set the complete property

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myurl",
  complete: function(){
              alert("complete");
            }
  //set all the other options as usual
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the callback to any of the jQuery AJAX methods to delay execution of another function until after the request is complete.

Example:

```
   $.post('/some/url', somedata, function() {
        // put the code you want to execute on completion here
   });
```

For more complicated scenarios, use the actual [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method which gives you hooks for success, completion, error and other events. Typically, you'd only need success and error.

```
   $.ajax( '/some/url', {
        data: somedata,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result) {
           // success code execution here
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error) {
           // error code here
        },
        complete: function(xhr,status) {
           // completion code here
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for a particular call, then the `complete` function is likely what you need.  If you want this to be global, for all ajax calls, then Nicola's answer should be what you need.

Here's the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for Ajax calls.